# What's up with my junk?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I noticed that I have a junk bag on the lower right hand side of my inventory screen:

[image]

I assumed it was to hold worthless material that can just be sold off whenever I find a merchant. However, when I click on it, it doesn't seem to do anything. As you can see in the picture, I currently have some junk in my inventory. Bones, the highlighted item, says in the description that it has "no real value". Shouldn't that item be living in this so-called junk bag?

So how does this junk bag work? I tried to drag things to it and that didn't work and clicking it doesn't do anything either. What am I missing?

Comment: Recommended question title: What's up with my Junk?

Comment: @Sterno Yeah, I'm a fan of goofy titles. I changed it. Lol

Comment: I was unsurprisingly mislead by the title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two ways that you can junk items.

- Click on the icon, *not the name*, of an item in your inventory and drag and drop it into the junk bag. If you try to drag and drop on the name instead of the icon, it doesn't drag.
- Right-click on an item in your inventory and select "Add to Junk".

[image]

**These options only work if the item is unequipped.**

Think of putting stuff in your junk bag as handy way of marking it as "sell this when I get back to town". When you talk to a shopkeeper, you have the option to sell everything in your junk bag.

You can view items in your junk bag by going to Inventory->Junk. You can remove items that you accidentally junked by viewing them in your junk bag, right-clicking, and selecting "Remove from Junk".

[image]

Also, when viewing items in your junk bag, you can select to destroy them, either individually by right-clicking and selecting "Destroy" or all together by selecting "Destroy All" at the bottom of the screen. You may find that you need to destroy some items if your inventory is getting because you're a greedy little thief like me who steals everything that isn't nailed down, even if you don't need it. After junking these stolen items, they may end up stuck in your junk bag because shopkeepers won't buy stolen goods. I assume there is a way to sell stolen items later in the game, but I haven't gotten that far yet.

Comment: Do you know if all junk says something like "Item has very little value", etc in the description? I would hate to sell stuff I need later.

Comment: I assume you mean "junk" as in "items that are worthless" as opposed to "items that might be awesome but which you put in your junk bag". "Junk bag" was probably a really awful thing for them to call it, since as far as I know anything you want to sell, ever, has to go into it. But as far as knowing if it's worthless, I don't know, and I have the same problem. I can't even how much an item will sell for until AFTER I sell it.

Comment: I have sold things that weren't in my junk bag. The merchants have an option for selling on the top right corner of their inventory menu. Then I just double click on the item that I want to sell.

Comment: @spugsley Awesome! Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: Just to let you know, stolen items can be sold if they are in your junk bag and you select the option that lets you sell it all at once :) Just found that out.

Comment: @spugsley Who did you sell to? When I tried it, it sold all the other stuff in my junk bag, but not the stolen items in there.

Comment: The lady in the blacksmith's house in Gorhart takes it from me. If I try to sell it outright she won't take it, but in the junk bag, she will. Maybe it's a weird bug in my game. Oh well, not complaining :p

Comment: @spugsley I just tried selling stolen items to her via the junk bag, but she wouldn't take them. Oh well!

Comment: Wow that's so weird! I just tried it again to make sure and she definitely took the stolen stuff.

Answer (score 0):

By right clicking and selecting "add to junk" the items will go into junk.  The most important quest items are not able to even goto junk in the first place.  All stolen items in the junk pile WILL NOT BE SOLD to any merchant UNLESS you have a maxed out merc skill OR sell to a "traveler" sales-individual.